# Para que serve a chave estrangeira (SQL)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Pelo que andei pesquisando, na hora de puxar a informação de duas tabelas em um banco de dados, usa-se o JOIN, que nada tem haver com chave estrangeira.

Então para que serve declarar um campo como foreign key (chave estrangeira)? Não vejo sentido. Alguem me explica por favor?

Comment: Integridade dos dados!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarar um campo como chave estrangeira explicita qual o campo que liga as duas tabelas no join, tanto para quem for produzir querys para ele, quanto para o próprio banco lidar com a otimização.

Um dos pontos primordiais da normatização em um banco de dados é garantir a integridade deles, declarando uma chave estrangeira, você se assegura de que aquele relacionamento ira acontecer sempre que for possível, não preenchendo a tabela com valores inexistentes na outra.

**Chave Estrangeira**

Uma chave estrangeira é chamada quando há o relacionamento entre duas tabelas.

Sempre em chave estrangeira vai haver relacionamentos entre tabelas, por exemplo, se uma tabela que tem uma chave primária de outra tabela.

**Junção de Tabela**

Tabela de banco de dados são semelhantes a conjuntos numeros e algumas vezes, precisamos achar a interseção entre eles, como pode ver abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estas tabelas são ligadas por um campo comum entre elas, estes campo deve ser a chave estrangeira entra elas.

**Normalização de Bancos de Dados Relacionais**

Normalização é um processo a partir do qual se aplicam regras a todas as tabelas do banco de dados com o objetivo de evitar falhas no projeto, como redundância de dados e mistura de diferentes assuntos numa mesma tabela.

[Leia Mais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)